# How to mirror one folder to another using rsync 3.x?

Tags: file-transfer, rsync

I have compiled rsync 3.0.9 just because the one included in Mavericks is so old.

Anyway, I am trying to mirror a folder in my main HDD in another HDD. I don't think it matters but both are connected via SATA and both are formatted as HFS (case-insentive and journaled).

I ran:

```
rsync -ahv --delete --exclude="my-exclude-file.txt" --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 --progress /sources/ /destination/
```

and it doesn't skip the m4a/mp3 files it has processed already!

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the itemised "-i" or "--itemize-changes" option to your command rsync will tell you why it is transferring the files.

For each file you'll see a strings that looks like ">f..t......". The format of the string is "YXcstpoguax". Y is the direction of the transfer. X is the type of object being transferred (for example 'f'ile, 'd'irectory). The rest of the string documents the changes.

- c for checksum
- s for size
- t for modification time
- p for permissions
- o for owner
- g for group
- u is currently reserved for future use
- a for ACL permissions
- x for extended attributes

So in my example above it transferred the file because the modification time was different.

This should help you identify why the files are still being transferred.

Comment: thank you so much. that led me to the reason why it keeps on copying over and over again! :) ps. I did use -i but I can never understood what it meant.